# Reset identity seed after in SQL Server in table filled with records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Table called `Person`, this table is non-empty and it's filled with records ( more than 1000 rows )

How can I reset the identity seed of this table?

| Id | PersonName |
| --- | --- |
| 154 | Alice |
| 155 | John |

The query was executed, but the table still has the identity

```
use [MyDatabase]
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.Person', RESEED, 0)
GO
```

Expected result of the table after executing the previous query :

| Id | PersonName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice |
| 2 | John |

Comment: *"I'm trying this query, but it won't work."* what does "won't work" mean?

Comment: The table was not reset ( identity seed won't change )

Comment: I can't replicate your problem in my sandbox. It works fine. Notice in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sBKB.png) that ID `1` has 2 rows. (Image because you can't use `DBCC` in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2710fe40284530e80019d643c0d0403a).)

Comment: The question is about a table with records , I will try to explicate and modify my question

Comment: The table clearly has data ***before*** I reseed it in the image. I `INSERT` 1000 rows into it *before* the `RESEED`. The intial `INSERT` (of 1,000 rows) is on lines 7-15, you can see me `SELECT` from that data on lines 18-20, then I `RESEED` on Line 22, before inserting another row on lines 24/25, and demonstrate that a duplicate ID is present after the `RESEED` on lines 27-29.

Comment: This won't work for me , I'm trying this more than 5 times .

Comment: What "won't work" for you..? You need to take the time here to provide a full [mre]; as I said, the thing you say "isn't working" *is* working in my attempt to replicate the problem.

Comment: I mean , I didn't get the expected result

Comment: If you want to alter IDs of *existing* rows, `CHECKIDENT` won't do anything for you. That requires an `UPDATE`, or else an `INSERT` into an empty table (you could rename the original table or move the rows first).

Comment: Ok, now we have sample data and expected results, the problem is your understanding; the code is very likely working **exactly** as it is supposed to, and as I demonstrated.. `RESEED` *resets* the value of the *next* `IDENTITY` generated, it doesn't change *any* of the existing values. You can't `UPDATE` the value of an `IDENTITY`. But *why* do you want to? An `IDENTITY` is just an arbitrary value, it's value doesn't matter.

Comment: No, in this case I need it as a primary key

Comment: So again, why does it matter what it's value is? it's just an arbitrary number.

Comment: I set it as a primary key , the identity seed ( `Id` ) is a primary key for the table `Person`

Comment: Yes, so why do you want to *change* the value of those Primary keys... You haven't answered my question.

Comment: I would like to reset the database , remove all data and add new records

Comment: Then do that, but the values of the `IDENTITY`s don't matter... If you want to ensure you specific specific values for the `INDENTITY`s then you would need to use ensure you enable `IDENTITY_INSERT` on the table and specify the value at **`INSERT`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your understanding; the code is very likely working **exactly** as it is supposed to, and as I demonstrated.. `RESEED` *resets* the value of the *next* `IDENTITY` generated, it doesn't change *any* of the existing values.

Take SQL similar to what I gave in the comments:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Person (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), AbligatoryColumn char(1));
GO

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT N1.N
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3)
INSERT INTO dbo.Person (AbligatoryColumn)
SELECT 'a'
FROM Tally;
GO

SELECT TOP (5) *
FROM dbo.Person
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

If you run this you get the follow results:

```
ID          AbligatoryColumn
----------- ----------------
1           a
2           a
3           a
4           a
5           a
```

Now, let's `RESEED` the table, and `INSERT` another row:

```sql
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.Person', RESEED, 0)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Person
DEFAULT VALUES;
GO
SELECT TOP (5) *
FROM dbo.Person
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

This gives the following data set:

```
ID          AbligatoryColumn
----------- ----------------
1           a
1           NULL
2           a
3           a
4           a
```

Notice that there are 2 rows where `ID` has a value of `1`. This is because the new row we inserted has used thenew seed, so the next value generated was `1` (as when you `RESEED` you are defining the last value used, not the next value to be).

Note that you can't `UPDATE` the value of an `IDENTITY`, so if we tried the following you would get an error:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.Person
SET ID = ID + 1000
WHERE AbligatoryColumn = 'a';
```

> Cannot update identity column 'ID'.

The *real* question *why* do you want to change the value? An `IDENTITY` is just an arbitrary value, it's value doesn't matter.

If you "must" (and I would suggest you don't need to) you would need to `CREATE` a new table, `INSERT` the data from your existing table into it (likely with `IDENTITY_INSERT` enabled) and then `DROP` your old table, and rename the new one. If you have any foreign key constraints pointing to your current table, you'll need to `DROP` ***all*** of these, and I *really* hope you have any data referencing the existing ID values, as you'll then need to update all the foreign key values *before* you recreate the foreign key constraints. As a result your new table would (albeit likely temporarily) need to have both the old and new PK values in separate columns.

So, in truth, leave it as it is; the value of an `IDENTITY` literally doesn't matter. It's an arbitrary value and it whether the first value  starts at `1`, `17`, or `-167` or if there are numbers "missing" is irrelevant to functionality of what `IDENTITY` is there to achieve; an always ascending value.

Comment: For completeness I'll mention that updating identity values is possible with an intermediate step that's potentially cheaper than inserting everything anew (depending on what you're updating): create a new table with the same structure as the old one, save for the `IDENTITY` constraint, use `ALTER TABLE SWITCH` to switch the data from the old table to the new table, perform any updates you please, then switch back. Of course this still requires dropping foreign keys if there are any and is not something to do lightly.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that, @JeroenMostert . An interesting work-around.